# Reference for solid state particle detector

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, particle-detectors

I'm looking for a good introductory text on solid state devices for particle detection.

Comment: The place to start is the Particle Data Book chapters on detection. Go to http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/reviews/contents_sports.html, select the "experimental methods" button and start reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gilmore's book:

[http://www.amazon.com/Single-Particle-Detection-Measurement-Gilmore/dp/0850667550](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0850667550)

Chapter 5 is on solid state ionization and it's use in detectors.  That was hanging around the lab when I was working in particle physics.  I'd give that one a try.  It's a bit old these days but the principles are there.

Answer (score 1):

I found this book pretty useful during studies:

[Detectors for particle radiation (Konrad Kleinknecht)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521648548)

It covers a lot of different detector types, and also has some chapters on solid state detectors, from the basics (particles in matter, semiconductors) up to how to build a detector out of it, if I recall correctly.